# Issue in edition upgrade of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to upgrade Enterprise edition to Standard edition, bit every time, the installer closes with following error in temp folder:

> 08/21/2016 17:14:46.226 Attempting to launch process C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2012\x64\ScenarioEngine.exe
>   08/21/2016 17:17:03.892 Process returned exit code: 0x80131604
>   08/21/2016 17:17:03.904 Local ScenarioEngine.exe returned exit code: 0x80131604
>   08/21/2016 17:17:03.906 Attempting to release setup mutex
>   08/21/2016 17:17:03.908 Setup mutex has been released
>   08/21/2016 17:17:03.910 Setup closed with exit code: 0x84C40013
>   08/21/2016 17:17:03.912

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall first?

Comment: If i uninstall sql server, all my data files will be gone. So i really cant uninstall

Comment: from what version to what version ?

Comment: That's not exactly an **upgrade** - Enterprise edition has much more features than Standard .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried steps of following link and it worked.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqljourney/2012/05/07/sql-20082008-r220122014-setup-disappearsfails-when-installing-setup-support-files/